# WiFi issues after upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10 - HP Envy dv6 quad core with rt2800pci

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, hp

This started happening after upgrading... about 2 days ago.

I have a Verizon FIOS (wireless) router... and the moment I step away from the room (approx. 20 feet away) where it is located, my wireless connection goes down...

I have pasted my syslog output below.  Bottom line is it disconnects and then keeps popping up a wireless authentication dialog, fails to connect after I input the password and then eventually drops the wifi connection.

I have seen a lot of wifi issues reported with the 13.04 upgrade... appreciate your help.

Note that with 12.10, this would happen occasionally (maybe once a week) but seemed to have no correlation to distance from router... and I would reboot to fix. But with 13.04, its unusable.

lspci output:

```
lspci | egrep -i "network|wireless|ethernet" 
0a:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 539b
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

lshw output (for network):

```
*-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: c4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:19 memory:74500000-745fffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Ralink corp.
            vendor: Ralink corp.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 00
            serial: 9c:2a:70:0b:81:5b
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.28 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:19 memory:74500000-7450ffff
```

SYSLOG (from the time I move away onwards, until prompt for wifi password):

```
May  2 10:07:22 athena wpa_supplicant[1224]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 [GTK=CCMP]
May  2 10:07:25  wpa_supplicant[1224]: last message repeated 3 times
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.235743] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 (Reason: 2)
May  2 10:07:25 athena wpa_supplicant[1224]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:7f:28:52:65:b9 reason=2
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.260107] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May  2 10:07:25 athena NetworkManager[1173]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265935] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265940] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265944] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265947] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265949] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265951] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.265954] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.266200] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271606] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271612] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271618] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271623] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271627] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271631] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271635] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena kernel: [ 2073.271639] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
May  2 10:07:25 athena NetworkManager[1173]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May  2 10:07:26 athena wpa_supplicant[1224]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 (SSID='10177-2' freq=2437 MHz)
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.059525] wlan0: authenticate with 00:7f:28:52:65:b9
May  2 10:07:26 athena NetworkManager[1173]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May  2 10:07:26 athena wpa_supplicant[1224]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 (SSID='10177-2' freq=2437 MHz)
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.074818] wlan0: send auth to 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 (try 1/3)
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.076306] wlan0: authenticated
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.078370] wlan0: associate with 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 (try 1/3)
May  2 10:07:26 athena NetworkManager[1173]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May  2 10:07:26 athena wpa_supplicant[1224]: wlan0: Associated with 00:7f:28:52:65:b9
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.085032] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:7f:28:52:65:b9 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=7)
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.085155] wlan0: associated
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.085264] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
May  2 10:07:26 athena NetworkManager[1173]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.091115] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
May  2 10:07:26 athena kernel: [ 2074.091120] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
```

Comment: I can work around this issue by using an older version of the kernel... During the upgrade, a 3.5.0-27 version was retained and I booted with that one and all seems well...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on 12.10, I solved it deleting Kwalletmanager and deleting Wireless configuration allocated on Knetworkmanager, after doing this it worked very well