# My internet connection turns off in 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, internet

I connect to the internet via wifi for several minutes, and then it disconnects without telling me anything (the image of internet connections says I am still connected). I have to click in my wireless network to connect again for a small period of time.

When I use another computer with Windows my internet never turns off. I believe I have used this computer with other wireless networks and the internet never shuts down. But also I have had the same problem with other wireless networks.

I have to say that I do not have much experience with network connections. Thanks for the support Ubuntu community.

Comment: please include result of `lspci` , `lshw -c network` & `lsmod`

Comment: also post the output of `tail /var/log/syslog` after your next disconnect

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a similar issue - see [WiFi issues after upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10 - HP Envy dv6 quad core with rt2800pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289582/wifi-issues-after-upgrade-to-13-04-from-12-10-hp-envy-dv6-quad-core-with-ra280)... seems like a recurring issue with 13.04 with wifi...

Comment: I was able to work around by booting with an older kernel.. during boot, hold down the ESC key and then under advanced select a 3.5.0-xx kernel instead of the default 3.8.x kernel