# Just installed 13.10 and everything is fine except I cannot connect to the internet. Any thoughts?

Tags: wireless, 13.10, internet

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my HP G62 laptop and the install went smoothly. I did the install off of a USB drive after trying ubuntu. While I was testing it, I connected to my Wireless with out issue and surfed a little. After the install, no wireless.

I can still connect to my wireless network (at least it tells me I'm connected at full strength) but No servers can be found. I attempted to ping Google to no avail and I attempted to ping my router to no avail.

I tried to then hard wire the machine and once again it told me that I was connected but I was not.

When I ran dmesg, I got the following message: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolvabe. Please install nss-hostname!

Is the hostname the issue? if so, how do I resolve it with out internet connection? If it's not the issue, how do I move forward?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT. I forgot to attach the image of my [ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcxlq.jpg) if that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only using IPV6? If that is not intentional then you have not assigned or leased an IPV4 IP address from your router / dhcp server. Have you also verified your DNS is correct?

Just found this link that might help... [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289582/wifi-issues-after-upgrade-to-13-04-from-12-10-hp-envy-dv6-quad-core-with-rt280)

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are both set to automatic. The link that you provided had me delete KWallet but I could not even find that program on the computer.

I also found and tried this in the forums but bcmwl-kernal-source was not installed and then I got FATAL: Module wl not found.